# How do I install the graphic drivers on an HP Workstation xw4100?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, nvidia, graphics, hp

Can someone help me install the graphic card of the **HP Workstation xw4100**?

The card info is:

```
Quadro4 980 XGL/AGP/SSE2
1.5.8 NVIDIA 96.43.20
```

I'm tried to install the **NVIDIA-Linux-x86-1.0-9639-pkg1.run** in init-3 mode. I could not succeed due to an *"Cant find kernel source on nvidia driver install"* error.

I managed to install the *nvidia_96* & *nvidia_96_updates* (installed but not activated) drivers.

Thx for your help! If you nedd more info, just let me know

Answer (score 1):

Before installing the nvidia drivers, you should first try installing them from System -> Administration -> Additional Drivers

[image: jocky]

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia for additional details.

If for some reason you feel you need to manually install the driver, you first need to install a few dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then run the Nvidia .run as root.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual for additional details.